# WCF generic proxy caller

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, wcf

I have an ASP.NET web-client and many WCF services. I used it this way:

```
public class UserController
{
    private Service1Client _service1Client = new Service1Client();  
    private Service2Client _service2Client = new Service2Client();

    public JsonResult HasDebts()
    {
        var user = _service1Client.GetUserByUsername(User.Identity.Name);
        return Json(_service2Client.HasDebts(user.Id));
    }
}
```

Recently, I have learned that all proxy clients should be closed or aborted after usage.
Now, I am trying to implement a universal generic service caller. At first, I have implemented a **generic caller**:

```
public static class ServiceCaller
{
    private static void CloseProxyProperly<T>(T serviceProxy)
        where T : ICommunicationObject, new()
    {
        if (serviceProxy.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            serviceProxy.Abort();
        else
            serviceProxy.Close();
    }

    public static void Use<T>(Action<T> action)
        where T : ICommunicationObject, new()
    {
        T serviceProxy = new T();
        try
        {
            action(serviceProxy);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy);
        }
    }

    public static void Use<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action)
        where T1 : ICommunicationObject, new()
        where T2 : ICommunicationObject, new()
    {
        T1 serviceProxy1 = new T1();
        T2 serviceProxy2 = new T2();
        try
        {
            action(serviceProxy1, serviceProxy2);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy1);
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy2);
        }
    }

    public static void Use<T1, T2, T3>(Action<T1, T2, T3> action)
        where T1 : ICommunicationObject, new()
        where T2 : ICommunicationObject, new()
        where T3 : ICommunicationObject, new()
    {
        T1 serviceProxy1 = new T1();
        T2 serviceProxy2 = new T2();
        T3 serviceProxy3 = new T3();
        try
        {
            action(serviceProxy1, serviceProxy2, serviceProxy3);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy1);
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy2);
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy3);
        }
    }

    public static TResult Use<T, TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func)
        where T : ICommunicationObject, new()
    {
        T serviceProxy = new T();
        TResult result;
        try
        {
            result = func(serviceProxy);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static TResult Use<T1, T2, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> func)
        where T1 : ICommunicationObject, new()
        where T2 : ICommunicationObject, new()
    {
        T1 serviceProxy1 = new T1();
        T2 serviceProxy2 = new T2();
        TResult result;
        try
        {
            result = func(serviceProxy1, serviceProxy2);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy1);
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy2);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static TResult Use<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult> func)
        where T1 : ICommunicationObject, new()
        where T2 : ICommunicationObject, new()
        where T3 : ICommunicationObject, new()
    {
        T1 serviceProxy1 = new T1();
        T2 serviceProxy2 = new T2();
        T3 serviceProxy3 = new T3();
        TResult result;
        try
        {
            result = func(serviceProxy1, serviceProxy2, serviceProxy3);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy1);
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy2);
            CloseProxyProperly(serviceProxy3);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var hasDebts = ServiceCaller.Use<Service1Client, Service2Client, bool>((svc1, svc2) => {
    var user = svc1.GetUserByUsername(User.Identity.Name);
    return svc2.HasDebts(user.Id);
});
```

I think that you will not be surprised if I tell you that I don't like it:

- code repetition
- inconvenient, three-storey, non-inferrable generic types
- makes it more difficult to read, debug and support code

I also tried to implement **`IDisposable` class with singleton clients**:

```
public class ServiceCaller : IDisposable 
{
    private Service1Client _service1Client;
    public Service1Client Service1Client { 
        get {
            return _service1Client ?? (_service1Client = new Service1Client()); }
        }
    }

    // ... other clients

    public void Dispose()
    {
        CloseProxyProperly(_service1Client); // with check for null inside
        // ... other clients
    }        
}

using (var sc = new ServiceCaller())
{
    var user = sc.Service1Client.FindUserByUsername(User.Identity.Name);
    return sc.Service2Client.HasDebts(user.Id);
}
```

However, it doesn't reduce code complexity and repetition. Moreover, if I add a new service reference to a project, I will have to modify this class - it sounds wrong.

The third guess it to make an **extension** and call it manually in ASP.NET:

```
public static class WcfServiceExtensions
{
    public static void SafeClose(this ICommunicationObject obj)
    {
        if (serviceProxy.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            serviceProxy.Abort();
        else
            serviceProxy.Close();
    }
}

public JsonResult HasDebts()
{
    var service1Client = new Service1Client();
    var service2Client = new Service2Client();

    var user = service1Client.GetUserByUsername(User.Identity.Name);
    var result = service2Client.HasDebts(user.Id);

    service1Client.SafeClose();
    service2Client.SafeClose();

    return result;
}
```

There is a code repetition. Again.

How do people solve this problem? What is the best way to wrap a WCF proxy call and close it properly?

Comment: If you control the WCF code and contract, try moving to a model as described [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=95). It makes it really easy to create a single proxy class (with just a few lines of code) that correctly closes the client in the background without your application code to know about it, and gives many other advantages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let the `Service1Client` and `Service2Client` (and the remaining clients) implement the `IDisposable` interface and let the `Dispose()` method take care about the closing of the `proxy`.

This would lead the `UserController` looking like

```
public class UserController
{
    public JsonResult HasDebts()
    {
        using (var _service1Client = new Service1Client())
        using (var _service2Client = new Service2Client())
        {
            var user = _service1Client.GetUserByUsername(User.Identity.Name);
            return Json(_service2Client.HasDebts(user.Id));
        }
    }
}
```

If those clients all share the same base object you could consider to let the base class implement `IDisposable`.

Based on this comment

> Unfortunatelly, these service clients are generated by Visual Studio. I can't change it and any changes will be overriden when I update service references

Because the generated service clients are [`System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TChannel>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects which implements `IDisposable` by default and the underlaying `Dispose()` method just calls `Close()`, you can use the `using` statement like shown above.

Edit based on latest comment stating

> Dispose() calls the proxy close() method, that sends a message from
>   the client to the service indicating that the connection session is no
>   longer needed. A problem can arise with this approach if there is an
>   exception when calling the close() method. This is why the using
>   approach is not recommended when calling WCF methods.

From [do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client](http://omaralzabir.com/do-not-use-using-in-wcf-client/)

> There are various reasons for which the underlying connection can be
>   at broken state before the using block is completed and the .Dispose()
>   is called. Common problems like network connection dropping, IIS doing
>   an app pool recycle at that moment, some proxy sitting between you and
>   the service dropping the connection for various reasons and so on.

So adding a extension method could be the way to go but a wrapper arround the client would be better (taken from the comments of the above link) like so

```
public class ServiceClientSafeDisposingWrapper<T> : IDisposable where T : ICommunicationObject
{
    private readonly T _serviceClient;

    public T Client
    {
        get { return _serviceClient; }
    }

    public ServiceClientSafeDisposingWrapper(T serviceClient)
    {
        if (serviceClient == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceClient"); }

        _serviceClient = serviceClient;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_serviceClient.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
        {
            _serviceClient.Abort();
        }
        else if (_serviceClient.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
        {
            _serviceClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

which then can be used like so

```
public class UserController
{
    public JsonResult HasDebts()
    {
        using (var _service1Client = new ServiceClientSafeDisposingWrapper<Service1Client>(new Service1Client()))
        using (var _service1Client = new ServiceClientSafeDisposingWrapper<Service2Client>(new Service2Client()))
        {
            var user = _service1Client.Client.GetUserByUsername(User.Identity.Name);
            return Json(_service2Client.Client.HasDebts(user.Id));
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe enclosing the action in `Dispose` inside a `try..catch` should be done too.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, these service clients are generated by Visual Studio. I can't change it and any changes will be overriden when I update service references.

Comment: `using` statement of client proxies is not recommented be either MSDN and "Programming WCF Services" author. "Dispose() calls the proxy close() method, that sends a message from the client to the service indicating that the connection session is no longer needed.
A problem can arise with this approach if there is an exception when calling the close() method. This is why the using approach is not recommended when calling WCF methods." http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/622989/WCF-and-the-Try-Catch-Abort-Pattern